# How can i convert DecimalField to float in Python Django?

Tags: python, django

I have this form field:

```
area = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=20)
```

When I post it I get unicode data:

```
raise Exception(type(a.get('area',))
```

the result is

> `<type 'unicode'>`

How can I convert that to float? I want to perform an arithmetic operation on the result.

If I do this:

```
float(a.get('area', '0'))
```

Then I get this

> float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: What's the `a`, could you post the code around it?

Comment: The parentheses in `raise Exception(type(a.get('area',))` are unbalanced. Could you recopy your code snippets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the form is processed and you get your `area` as `<type 'unicode'>` then this should suffice to convert it and perform arithmetic on it.

```
area = form.data['area']
#area should be <type 'unicode'>
area_float = float(area)
```

Consider the following example

```
a = u'1.34'
a_float = float(a)
type(a_float)
>> <type 'float'>
```

However considering that a `DecimalField` uses Pythons `decimal` type internally and is different from pythons `float` which is used by `FloatField`.

[Decimal Type](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html#decimal) read more here about the decimal type.

Comment: My problem is that sometime area is coming as None , then it can't convert to float. how can make the None to 0

Comment: Then you would have to override your `clean()` or `is_valid()` methods or set it to `0` like this `form.data['area'] = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Form submissions are strings (excepted when files are being uploaded, I think.) In Django, the form is automatically converted to the appropriate Python type if the form is valid (how convenient!) You access the data using via `cleaned_data` (see [Processing the data from the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#processing-the-data-from-a-form).)

In this case, you might do something like:

```
if form.is_valid():
   # Form is valid, so do stuff with the form data
   # e.g. send email, save to DB etc.
   area = form.cleaned_data['area']
   # more code here
```

Comment: Is there any way to type cast string or unicode to float or decimal because i am not using cleaned data

Answer (score 0):

you can use this with your variable containing you r data.
{variable|Floatformat} I have been using this in the templates .
May be that can help .:)